# No resource identifier found for attribute 'entryImages'

Tags: java, javascript, android, xml

I have changed package name in androidmanifest.xml. But getting this error while going to recompile.

\res\xml\utils.xml error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'entryImages' in package 'com.whatsapp.plus'
```

Here is the lines which the error is in utils.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/plus_version"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:robobunny="http://robobunny.com"
xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">

<com.whatsapp.plus.ImageListPreference 
android:entries="@array/bubble_style"
android:title="@string/bubble_style_title"
android:key="bubble_style_list"
android:summary="@string/bubble_style_summary"
android:defaultValue="0"
android:entryValues="@array/bubble_values"
cmwmobile:entryImages="@array/bubbles_images" />

<com.whatsapp.plus.ImageListPreference
android:entries="@array/appicons_style"
android:title="@string/appicons_title"
android:key="appicons_list"
android:defaultValue="0"
android:entryValues="@array/appicons_values"
cmwmobile:entryImages="@array/appicons_images" />

<com.whatsapp.plus.ImageListPreference
android:entries="@array/notifybar_colors"
android:title="@string/notifybar_colors_title"
android:key="notifybar_colors_list"
android:summary="@string/notifybar_colors_summary"
android:defaultValue="0"
android:entryValues="@array/notifybar_values"
cmwmobile:entryImages="@array/notifybar_icons" />
```

Comment: Which ide/build system are you using? After changing package name you have to regenerate R.java file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in ADT I suggest first undo your renaming of your package (I'm assuming you manually renamed it) and get everything working again.

**To rename your Application Package**:
From the package explorer in ADT right click on your project. Select Android Tools->Rename Application Package.

Review the changes and select finish. The changes should hopefully show you what you missed when attempting to manually rename